# "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running into the error

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table

whenever I try to add a new entry to my tables. Here is my SQL code:

SQL DDL

```
CREATE TABLE ART_OBJECT
(
    Id_no NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    Artist VARCHAR(20),
    Year INT UNIQUE,
    Title VARCHAR(20),
    Description VARCHAR(20),
    Style VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);

ALTER TABLE ART_OBJECT
    ADD CONSTRAINT ArtistName FOREIGN KEY (Artist) REFERENCES ARTIST(Name)

ALTER TABLE ART_OBJECT
    ADD CONSTRAINT EName FOREIGN KEY (Title) REFERENCES EXHIBITIONS(Name)

CREATE TABLE ARTIST
(
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    DateBorn DATE,
    Date_died DATE ,
    Country_of_origin VARCHAR(20),
    Epoch INT,
    Main_style VARCHAR(20),
    Description VARCHAR(20)
);

ALTER TABLE ARTIST
    ADD CONSTRAINT TimeMade FOREIGN KEY (Epoch) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Year)

CREATE TABLE PERMANENT_COLLECTION
(
    Date_acquired DATE,
    Status VARCHAR(20),
    Cost NUMBER,
    Year INT,
    ArtID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE PERMANENT_COLLECTION
    ADD CONSTRAINT TimeMade FOREIGN KEY (Year) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Year)

ALTER TABLE PERMANENT_COLLECTION
    ADD CONSTRAINT PCID FOREIGN KEY (ArtID) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)

CREATE TABLE BORROWED
(
    Id_no NUMBER,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Date_borrowed DATE,
    Date_returned DATE
);

ALTER TABLE BORROWED
    ADD CONSTRAINT BID FOREIGN KEY (Id_no) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)

ALTER TABLE BORROWED
    ADD CONSTRAINT BName FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES COLLECTIONS(CName)


CREATE TABLE PAINTING
(
    Paint_type VARCHAR(20),
    Drawn_on VARCHAR(20),
    Style VARCHAR(20),
    ArtID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE PAINTING
    ADD CONSTRAINT PStyle FOREIGN KEY (Style) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Style)

ALTER TABLE PAINTING
    ADD CONSTRAINT PID FOREIGN KEY (ArtID) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)

CREATE TABLE SCULPTURE
(
    Material VARCHAR(20),
    Height VARCHAR(20),
    Weight VARCHAR(20),
    Style VARCHAR(20),
    ArtID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE SCULPTURE
    ADD CONSTRAINT SCStyle FOREIGN KEY (Style) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Style)

ALTER TABLE PAINTING
    ADD CONSTRAINT SCID FOREIGN KEY (ArtID) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)


CREATE TABLE STATUE
(
    Material VARCHAR(20),
    Height VARCHAR(20),
    Weight VARCHAR(20),
    Style VARCHAR(20),
    ArtID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE STATUE
    ADD CONSTRAINT STStyle FOREIGN KEY (Style) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Style)

ALTER TABLE STATUE
    ADD CONSTRAINT STID FOREIGN KEY (ArtID) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)

CREATE TABLE OTHER
(
    Type VARCHAR(20),
    Style VARCHAR(20),
    ArtID NUMBER
);

ALTER TABLE OTHER
    ADD CONSTRAINT OStyle FOREIGN KEY (Style) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Style)

ALTER TABLE OTHER
    ADD CONSTRAINT OID FOREIGN KEY (ArtID) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)


CREATE TABLE COLLECTIONS
(
    CName VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Type VARCHAR(20),
    Description VARCHAR(20),
    Address VARCHAR(20),
    Phone VARCHAR(20),
    Contact_person VARCHAR(20),
);

CREATE TABLE EXHIBITIONS
(
    Name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    Start_date DATE,
    End_date DATE,
    E_id NUMBER,
);

ALTER TABLE EXHIBITIONS
    ADD CONSTRAINT EID FOREIGN KEY (E_id) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)


CREATE TABLE EXHIBITS_IN
(
    Id_no NUMBER,
    CName VARCHAR(20)
);

ALTER TABLE EXHIBITS_IN
    ADD CONSTRAINT EIID FOREIGN KEY (Id_no) REFERENCES ART_OBJECT(Id_no)

ALTER TABLE EXHIBITS_IN
    ADD CONSTRAINT EIName FOREIGN KEY (CName) REFERENCES COLLECTIONS(CName)
```

Database relations table for reference:

[DB Relations Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVNEq.png)

EER diagram for reference:

[EER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVlr1.png)

Comment: Please check the foreign key constraints. You are trying to create a FK by referring Name in ARTIST table, but table ARTIST does not exist at the first step. Create the independent table first followed by dependent tables in proper order.

Comment: @Arun mentioned the acceptable solution. But often it does not fit for extremely large schemes.  You should create the tables firstly, then apply foreign key restrictions. It can be reached with just reordering the operators in your query. It is the most reliable and fast way to do it.